# How can I include makefiles using a $(foreach ) expansion of a macro list?

Tags: gnu-make

How can I do something like the following?

```
DIRS =      app_interface/capi  \
            chip/dep/chal       \
            chip/dep/common     \
            chip/dep/ml         \
            chip/indep          \
            cli/test_project    \
            platform/reg_access \
            platform/utils

$(foreach dir,$(DIRS),-include $(dir)/.build/object_files.mk)

all:
    ... remainder of the makefile
```

Where essentially I'd like the `$(foreach ...)` statement to effectively be:?

```
-include app_interface/capi/.build/object_files.mk
-include chip/dep/chal/.build/object_files.mk
... and so forth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not the other way around?

```
DIRS = foo bar/moo

-include $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(dir)/.build/object_files.mk)
```

Comment: Even simpler could be `-include $(addsuffix /.build/object_files.mk,$(DIRS))`

Comment: @MadScientist I never considered that `include` in the makefile could take more than one file in it's argument list.

Comment: For my memory, remembering `foreach` is simpler than remembering `foreach`, `addsuffix`, `addprefix` and that the latter two even exist. But that might be just me.

Comment: `include` can take anywhere from zero arguments to as many as will fit in your makefile, without error.